# Stop backgrounds looping in HTML

Tags: html, background, repeat

I'm building a site for a Sega Dreamcast, so the HTML code it uses is very old and it doesn't understand CSS, HTML5 or any of that stuff.

I know how to add the background image itself , but I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the background from looping using only basic HTML code? Like a  style command, though I know that one doesn't work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always use `inline-style` to override any other styles. If I get your question right, You are looking for a `background-repeat:no-repeat;` property.

Comment: Yes, something like that, but in HTML code.
That's a CSS code, which won't work on the Sega Dreamcast - it's browser is from 1999-2002. Do you know the HTML code for it?